# Segmentation fault occur while reading content from file in object C++

Tags: c++, file, file-io, c++14, fstream

In my code first I stored the name and mobile number in one object after that I write that object into one text file using fstream.write() method. It successfully works, but when I read that written content into another object and call the display method then it displays data correctly, but it gives me segmentation fault after printing data.
Here is my code -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class Telephone
{
private:
    string name="a";
    int phno=123;
public:
    void getTelephoneData()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Name:";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter Phone Number:";
        cin>>phno;
    }
    void displayData()
    {
        cout<<"Name\t\tPhone no"<<endl;
        cout<<name<<"\t\t"<<phno<<endl;
    }

    void getData() {
        Telephone temp;
        ifstream ifs("Sample.txt",ios::in|ios::binary);
        ifs.read((char*)&temp,sizeof(temp));
        temp.displayData();
    }   
};
int main()
{
    Telephone t1;
    t1.getTelephoneData();
    cout<<"----Writing Data to file------"<<endl;
    ofstream ofs("Sample.txt",ios::out|ios::binary);
    ofs.write((char*)&t1,sizeof(t1));
    ofs.close();
    t1.getData();
}
```

Please help me where I'm wrong.
Thanks in advance...!

Comment: the problem is that you should write serialization/deserialization functions for `Telephone` class manually since it has `std::string` member which stores data on the heap and not inside the class object itself. See @Jerry Jeremiah comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038909/c-read-write-class-from-to-binary-file)

Comment: +1 You serialize the pointer in std::string to the string data. I would suggest to overload a stream operator for your class where you write the string and the integer manually in a file.

Comment: OK thanks for giving me solution..

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo, not quite. He stores the pointer to internals of a living `Telephone` object `t1`, then sets the same pointer to internals for a new object `temp`, so those two end up sharing the internals without knowing it. So when `temp` goes out of scope it destroys internals and when destructor of `t1` tries to delete already deleted internals it miserably fails

Comment: Please post your answer with some code I tried to modify my code with your comments but it not works. I'm not understand what to do?

Comment: As one more rule of thumb, consider code wrong that uses C-style casts (`(char*)&t1`). Whenever you think you need that, you are probably wrong.

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov Actually not. The pointer to Telephone object doesn't get serialized, you only give it to write, so it can lookup the data there. The problem is that in the Telephone data are at least a pointer to dynamic memory from string.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It actually resolves to a reinterpret_cast, it would be better to write it explicitely to show what is going on. And with a proper serialization approach you will not need it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, before I give you a solution, let's briefly talk about what is going on here:

`ofs.write((char*)&t1,sizeof(t1));`

What you are doing is casting t1 to a pointer to char, and saying 'write to ofs the memory representation of t1, as is'. So we have to ask ourselves: what is this memory representation of t1?

1. You are storing a (implementation defined, most probably 4 byte) integer
2. You are also storing a complex std::string object.

Writing the 4 byte integer might be OK. It is definitely not portable (big-endian vs little endian), and you might end up with the wrong int if the file is read on a platform with different endianness.

Writing the `std::string` is definitely not OK. Strings are complex object, and they most often allocate storage on the heap (although there is such a thing as small string optimization). What this means is that you're going to serialize a pointer to a dynamically allocated object. This will never work, as reading the pointer back would point to some location in memory that you have absolutely no control of. This is a great example of undefined behavior. Anything goes, and anything might happen with your program, including 'appearing to work correct' despite deeply seated problems.
In your specific example, because the Telephone object that was created is still in memory, what you get is 2 pointers to the same dynamically allocated memory. When your `temp` object goes out of scope, it deletes that memory.

When you return to your main function, when `t1` goes out of scope, it tries to delete the same memory again.

Serializing any kind of pointers is a big no-no. If your object internals consist of pointers, you need to make a custom solution of how those pointers will be stored in your stream, and later read to construct a new object. A common solution is to store them 'as if' they were stored by value, and later, when reading the object from storage, allocate memory dynamically and put the contents of the object in the same memory. This will obviously not work if you are trying to serialize the case where multiple objects point to the same address in memory: if you try to apply this solution, you would end up with multiple copies of your original object.

<s>Fortunately, for the case of a `std::string` this problem is easily solved, as strings have overloaded `operator<<` and `operator>>`, and you don't need to implement anything to make them work.</s>

*edit: Just using `operator<<` and `operator>>` won't work for `std::string`, explained a bit later why.*

### How to make it work:

There are many possible solutions, and I'm going to share one here. 
The basic idea is that you should serialize every member of your Telephone structure individually, and rely on the fact that every member know how to serialize itself. I am going to ignore the problem of cross-endianness compatibility, to make the answer a bit briefer, but if you care about cross platform compatibility, you should think about it.

My basic approach is to override `operator<<` and `operator>>` for the class telephone.

I declare two free functions, that are friends of the Telephone class. This would allow them to poke at the internals of different telephone objects to serialize their members.

```
class Telephone { 
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Telephone& telephone);
   friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Telephone& telephone);
   // ... 
};
```

*edit: I initially had the code for serializing the strings wrong, so my comment that it's fairly straightforward is plain-out wrong*

The code for implementing the functions has a surprising twist. Because  `operator>>` for strings stops reading from the stream when encountering a whitespace, having a name that is not a single word, or with special characters would not work, and put the stream in a state of error, failing to read the phone number. To go around the problem, i followed the example by @Michael Veksler and stored the length of the string explicitly. My implementation looks as follows:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Telephone& telephone)
{
    const size_t nameSize = telephone.name.size();
    os << nameSize;
    os.write(telephone.name.data(), nameSize);
    os << telephone.phno;
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Telephone& telephone)
{
    size_t nameSize = 0;
    is >> nameSize;
    telephone.name.resize(nameSize);
    is.read(&telephone.name[0], nameSize);
    is >> telephone.phno;
    return is;
}
```

Please note, that you must make sure that the data you write matches the data you're going to later try to read. If you store a different amount of information, or the arguments are in the wrong order, you will not end up with a valid object. If you later do any kind of modifications to the Telephone class, by adding new fields that you would want saved, you'll need to modify *both* functions.

To support names with spaces in them, the way you read the names from cin should be modified as well. One way would be to use `std::getline(std::cin, name);` instead of `cin >> name`

Finally, how you should serialize and deserialize from those streams:
Don't use the `ostream::write()` and `istream::read()` functions - use instead the `operator<<` and `operator>>` that we have overriden.

```
void getData() {
    Telephone temp;
    ifstream ifs("Sample.txt",ios::in|ios::binary);
    ifs >> temp;
    temp.displayData();
} 

void storeData(const Telephone& telephone) {
    ofstream ofs("Sample.txt",ios::out|ios::binary);
    ofs << telephone;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the name has white-space in it. For example if `telephone.name=="John Doe"`. Then it will read `telephone.name=="John"`, and then try to read `"Doe"` into `telephone.phno`, which will fail and put the stream into an error state.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I missed that. I'm editing my post.

Comment: well, you already answered the question completely, spaces are different problem which get solved by storing size of a string or using separators others than whitespace. @divinas I suggest you mark the answer

Answer (score 3):

## problem

You can't simply dump `std::string` objects into a file. Notice that `std::string` is defined as

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
```

When `std::string` can't avoid it, it uses `std::allocator<char>` to allocate heap memory for the string. By writing your `Telephone` object with `ofs.write((char*)&t1,sizeof(t1))`, you are also writing the `std::string` it contains as a collection of bits. Some of these `std::string` bits can be pointers obtained from `std::allocator`. These pointers point to heap memory which contains the characters of the string.

By calling `ofs.write()` the program writes the pointers, but not the characters. Then when the string is read with `ifs.read()`, it has pointers to unallocated heap, that does not contain the characters. Even if it did point to a valid heap, by some miracle, it would still not contain the characters it should have. Sometimes you may be *lucky*, and the program will not crash because the strings were short enough to avoid heap allocation, but it is completely unreliable.

## solution

You must write your own serialization code for this class, rather than rely on `ofs.write()`. There are several ways to do it. First of all, you can use [boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). You can simply follow the examples in the [linked tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) and make serialization work for you.

Another option is to do everything from scratch yourself. Of course, it is better to use existing code (like boost), but it could be a good learning experience to implement it yourself. By implementing yourself, you can better understand what boost might do under the hood:

```
void writeData(std::ostream & out) const {
    unsigned size = name.size();
    out.write((char*)&size, sizeof(size));
    out.write(name.data(), size);

    out.write((char*)&phno, sizeof(phno));
}
```

Then in `getData` read it in the same order. Of course, you have to allocate the string dynamically to the correct size, and then fill it with `ifs.read()`.

Unlike with `operator<<` for strings, this technique works well for any type of string. It will work well with strings that contain any character, including spaces and null characters (`\0`). The `operator>>` technique won't work with strings that have spaces, such as first-name last-name combinations, since it stops at white-spaces.

---

Note that there are specialized allocators that make serialization/deserialization trivial. Such an allocator can allocate the string from inside a pre-allocated buffer, and use fancy pointers (such as [boost::interprocess::offset_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html)) into this buffer. It is then possible to simply dump the whole buffer and reread it later with no hassle. For some reason, this approach is not commonly used.

---

## Critical:

Security is an issue. If the data is not under your control, then it can be used to hack your system. In my serialization example, the worse that can be is to run out of memory. Running out of memory could be an attack vector for denial of service, or worse. Maybe you should limit the max-size of the string, and manage the error.

Another thing to consider is interoperability across systems. Not all systems represent `int` or `long` the same way. For example, on 64-bit linux, `long` is 8 bytes, while on MS-Windows it is 4 bytes. The simplest solution is to use `out<<size<<' '` to write the size, but make sure to use C locale, otherwise four digit lengths can have commas or dots in them, which will spoil the parsing.